# select 2 tables / multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select, multiple-columns

I have this following query

```
SELECT *
FROM tablea,
     tableb
WHERE tablea.a = tableb.b 
  AND partner_id = 1
```

okay, this works fine, but I want SELECT from multiple columns, for example:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablea,
     tableb
WHERE tablea.a = tableb.b OR tableb.c OR tableb.d OR tableb.e OR...
  AND partner_id = 1
```

but this return with zero

ohh, it's look like funny, but what's the problem?

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current statement is being parsed as:

```
WHERE (tablea.a = tableb.b) OR (tableb.c) OR (tableb.d) OR (tableb.e) OR...
```

You must either explicitly compare against `tablea.a` in each clause or else use MySQL's [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) operator:

```
WHERE tablea.a IN (tableb.b, tableb.c, tableb.d, tableb.e, ...)
```